# The Query returns the correct number of rows but row 1 is lost

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The below query returns 171 rows, which is correct. But when I run the for loop code, it always starts at row 2 instead of 1. What am I doing wrong? I ran the echoed code in my SQL editor and I got the correct values from 1 to 171.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, DATE_FORMAT(som_moyr, '%m') AS twomo, MONTHNAME(som_moyr) AS month, EXTRACT(year FROM som_moyr) AS year, aom_moyr, sb_moyr, vb_moyr, hmh_moyr, tog_moyr, wdb_moyr, unit, charter, status    FROM BSA_Awards WHERE som_moyr > '0000-00-00' AND som_moyr < '2016-01-07' ORDER BY som_moyr DESC

for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) { 

$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo("num rows= $num_rows i= $i firstname= $firstname");

}
```

If I leave the DESC off the query I get the entire list and all rows are present but they are in the wrong order for my need. The DESC is obviously causing the issue but how and why?

Comment: Start loop with `$i = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

try loop sart with 0 ,i think it will work.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, DATE_FORMAT(som_moyr, '%m') AS twomo, MONTHNAME(som_moyr) AS month, EXTRACT(year FROM som_moyr) AS year, aom_moyr, sb_moyr, vb_moyr, hmh_moyr, tog_moyr, wdb_moyr, unit, charter, status    FROM BSA_Awards WHERE som_moyr > '0000-00-00' AND som_moyr < '2016-01-07' ORDER BY som_moyr DESC

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) { 

$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo("num rows= $num_rows i= $i firstname= $firstname");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `$i = 1;` in the for loop. Try `$i = 0;`

**UPDATE:**

From the code you posted in the comments, the reason why you're starting at row 2 in the for loop is due to the fact that you are calling `$sql->fetch();` once before the loop. This returns the first row. When the loop executes and you call `$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` this will return the next row.

Also, a warning about using the [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function for a SELECT statement. It is not guaranteed to work as the documentation states:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Comment: I've tried all of the ideas above none of them changes the result. I've done $i=0; $i<$num_obs and $i<=$num_obs all of them failed. All still gave me row two as row one.

Comment: I assume you meant $num_rows instead of $num_obs. it should be $i = 0; $ < $num_rows; $i++. Can you show how you are executing the query?

Comment: This is the page if interested;  http://bsaroundtable.org/awards.php?award=1&sort=2

Comment: Sorry, I meant show the code for how you are executing the query and getting $num_rows.

Comment: $sql = $db_found->prepare("$thequery");   
 $sql->execute();
 $result = $sql->fetch();
 
 //print_r ($result);

 $num_rows = $sql->rowCount();

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++)
```

Start `$i=0` and `$i<$num_rows`

Comment: When I remove the "DESC" from the 'order by' clause it works. But of course it leaves my data in the wrong order.